# How to open a modal box with an option selected (bootstrap)

Tags: select, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a modal box by selecting a specific option in a select box. 
Here's my fiddle with some of my code.
Can anyone help me?
http://jsfiddle.net/pfrutuoso/n9eu89et/6/

```
<label>Recinto</label>
            <select class="form-control" onchange='this.form.submit()' id="cria-recinto">
              <option>O meu coliseu</option>
              <option>volvo</option>
              <option>A minha arena</option>
              <option>a garagem da minha vizinha</option>
              <option>Na esquina</option>
            </select>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "volvo") {
        $('#cria-recinto').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Modal will show when you change the option to "volvo".

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k3c37k5t/2/)

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't work. the screen turns black only for a second with no content.

Comment: Yes @makshh. Thank you so mutch

Comment: By the way, remember to not use two IDs with the same name in one HTML page (in your fiddle modal and select has the same id).